# AutoCompleteTextView not showing results

Tags: java, android, arraylist, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to get my AutoCompleteTextView to show results but no matter what examples or solutions I look for I can't get it to show results. I've checked it in debug and the adapter has all values in it but its won't show a drop down

main.xml

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/spinnerDropDown"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>
```

Main.java

```
spinnerdropdown = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDropDown);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter=
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                locations
        );
    spinnerdropdown.setThreshold(0);
    stringArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinnerdropdown.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
    spinnerdropdown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

locations is a String ArrayList

Comment: stringArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); should be only after setAdapter.

Comment: true. Doesn't fix the problem though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setContentView()(To set the layout on an activity) should be the called first before finding any views within that layout.
Try this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
spinnerdropdown = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDropDown);
ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter=
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            locations 
    ); 
spinnerdropdown.setThreshold(1); 
spinnerdropdown.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
spinnerdropdown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this , it works.

```
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        spinnerdropdown = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDropDown);

        stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, languages);

        spinnerdropdown.setThreshold(0);
        stringArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        spinnerdropdown.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
        spinnerdropdown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```